# Why don't I have any books to place on the pedestal for "At the Summit of Apocrypha"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I'm on the last stage of *At the Summit of Apocrypha*, where supposedly the books collected during the previous chapters must be placed in the correct pedestals. However, upon interacting with any of the pedestals to select a book to place, the only option present is "None".

[image: "The pedestal stands empty. What book would you like to place?" <None>]

Even after reloading an older save and going through *Waking Dreams* again, this situation still occurs. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear: do you have the books called *Boneless Limbs*, *Delving Pincers*, *Prying Orbs*, and *Gnashing Blades*?

Comment: @JohnLaviolette Well, I picked them up, but they are not in my inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the comment, those books are not in your inventory. You *need* those books in your inventory to be able to place them on their respective pedestals.

From the [At the Summit of Apocrypha wikia page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/At_the_Summit_of_Apocrypha):

> The pedestal with the fangs – Gnashing Blades
>
> The pedestal with the pincers – Delving Pincers
>
> The pedestal with the tentacles – Boneless Limbs
>
> The pedestal with the eye – Prying Orbs

Since you should've been forced to pick them up in order to get to the point you are at now, I'm not entirely sure how you don't have them anymore. Luckily, you're on PC, so you could just use console commands to add them to your inventory. Here are the Item IDs of each book:

- On Apocrypha: Boneless Limbs: XX03A35F
- On Apocrypha: Delving Pincers: XX03A360
- On Apocrypha: Gnashing Blades: XX03A361
- On Apocrypha: Prying Orbs: XX03A362

Comment: I ended up doing that. Never really understood how that happened, when the books were collected, none of them appeared appeared in the inventory.

Comment: @Kroltan that's really weird. Sounds like a bug.